# Reloading UITableView data from downloaded plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, plist

first of all, I am really fairly new to objective-c and ios development.

I have a .plist which is downloaded from the internet and is then used to populate the UITableView. I can get this to work during the ApplicationDidLaunch method in the AppDelegate as follows.

```
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
NSURL *theFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8068058/Data.plist"];
NSDictionary *replace = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theFileURL];
if (replace != nil){
    [replace writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Then I set it as the DataPath

```
NSString *Path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
self.data = tempDict;
[tempDict release];
```

That is all fine, then I populate the TableView and display it. If I add a 'refresh' button to the NavgationController that displays the table. When I press it and run the same download code followed by

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I get nothing, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: is your table view hooked up?

Comment: I have the following code for the table view.

    self.tableDataSource = tempArray;

I then have code to set the tabeDataSource to objectAtKey for the plist. 

The table populates fine on first run, but I can't refresh the data while the app is running

Comment: i mean, is your table view hooked up with controller, etc in Storyboard/IB?

Comment: Yes, the tableview is connected in the RootViewController in interface builder

Comment: by getting nothing you mean that the tableview is empty?

Comment: I have managed now to get the table to refresh but the cells have no text but there are the correct amount of rows all with disclosure indicators.

Comment: If I close out of the app and go back into it the table is fine, its only when it is refreshed during run time

Answer (score 0):

Although you already solved your problem, I should point out some things that it would be better to change.

1. The code written above shouldn't be placed in the App Delegate. You should place it in the View Controller that handles the TableView. This will be more efficient at launch and much more object oriented.
2. If you are planning on submitting this app to the store, you should be careful about storing downloaded data in the `NSDocumentsDirectory`. If the user won't be able to edit the data at anytime, I **strongly recommend you** to save it in the `NSCachesDirectory`. If not try with the `NSLibraryDirectory`. Since iOS5 Apple doesn't like that you store downloaded data in the `NSDocumentsDirectory`.
3. Talking about caching, you should cache your data in some way. In the code above posted you are downloading the data and saving it each time you run the app. This is kind of pointless, because your app will not work if you have no internet connection, and there's no point of saving the plist if you are never loading it.
4. Another thing that I **strongly recommend** is to perform the network fetch in a secondary `queue`. The main queue will be blocked if you perform network fetches on it. I know that in this case this is barely noticeable because the file size is small, but if you have a bad internet connection you will notice how the UI is blocked.

I'm pointing out these things because when I started developing for iOS I faced the same troubles. If you wan't more information about how to do this, feel free to ask :)